# How to convert a DateTime object to hours in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to subtract the date values that are contained in separated lists and store only the results that are less than 24 hours and convert them into hours. This is the code I have so far:

```
#stored lists of dates

closure_date = ['2017-06-13 11:00:00', '2017-06-09 11:00:00', '2017-06-02 11:00:00']
opening_date = ['2017-06-13 05:00:00', '2017-06-09 05:00:00', '2017-06-02 05:00:00']

results = []

#Subtract the dates
results.append([datetime.strptime(c,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(o,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for c, o in zip(closure, opening) if datetime.strptime(c,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(o,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')<timedelta(hours=24)])
```

The result I get is a double list with the results that are less than 24 hours in seconds format.

```
[[datetime.timedelta(0, 21600), datetime.timedelta(0, 21600)]]
```

One approach I tried was to get those seconds from the results list and then divide each result by 3600 to get the hours format, something like:

```
for r in results:
    hour.append(r.datetime.timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()/3600)
```

But this is not possible because I get the error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'datetime'** which is reasonable since the results are in a double list and I would need another index to extract each result from the most inner list, IMO not simple to manipulate and I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this goal.

How can I obtain the seconds into hours from the double list in a better and simplistic way to manipulate later for doing other arithmetic calculations?

Comment: Take a look at https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple things going on here.

First you are getting a list of a list because you're using `append()`, which adds an item to a list. In this case, the item is itself a list: the result of your list comprehension. If you don't want this and simply want to add the items of an iterable to the list you should you `extend()`. However since you're using a list comprehension to create a list (the `[for ... in ...if...]`) you should change your code to get rid of the

```
results = []
```

And simply do

```
#Subtract the dates
results = [datetime.strptime(c,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(o,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for c, o in zip(closure, opening) if datetime.strptime(c,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(o,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')<timedelta(hours=24)]
```

because the result is a list itself.

Then you can iterate over `results` and do the calculation you want.

However, IMHO I think you're over complicating things by using a list comprehension here. Your code would be much more reasonable if you just wrote out the for loop longhand.

```
results = []
for c, o in zip(closing, opening):
    delta_t = datetime.strptime(c,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(o,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for c, o in zip(closure, opening)
    if delta_t < timedelta(hours=24):
        results.append(delta_t.total_seconds() / 3600)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! This definitely solved my problem and the code is neat and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

With [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, this can be done easily

```
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

closure_date = [
    '2017-06-13 11:00:00', '2017-06-09 11:00:00', '2017-06-02 11:00:00']
opening_date = [
    '2017-06-13 05:00:00', '2017-06-09 05:00:00', '2017-06-02 05:00:00']


results = [
    int((parse(c) - parse(o)).total_seconds() / 3600)
    for c, o in zip(closure_date, opening_date)
    if parse(c) - parse(o) < datetime.timedelta(hours=24)]


>>> results = [6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as concise as yours, but I find it easier to read.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
closure_date = ['2017-06-13 11:00:00', '2017-06-09 11:00:00', '2017-06-02 11:00:00']
opening_date = ['2017-06-13 05:00:00', '2017-06-09 05:00:00', '2017-06-02 05:00:00']

results = []
for closing, opening in zip(closure_date, opening_date):
    delta = datetime.strptime(closing, datetime_format) - datetime.strptime(opening, datetime_format)
    if(delta < timedelta(hours=24)):
        results.append(delta.seconds / 3600)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```